# Kivy Application Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x40 in tid 10919 (SDLThread) after opening the app in the android device

Tags: kivy, segmentation-fault, kivymd, buildozer

Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x40 in tid 10919 (SDLThread), pid 10882 (org.test.myapp)

this it the last line of the logcat, I am really clueless on what happened because even if I revert everything that I applied, even in the first ever deployment build that I am sure will work on my device because I've tried it before now gives the above error, but when I use my friends phone on an android 10 device it works flawlessly. below is my buildozer spec file... some say it might be a native library issue wherein 32bit libraries cannot work with a 64bit library

```
requirements = android,python3,kivy,kivymd,certifi,pillow,camera4kivy,gestures4kivy,numpy,keras,opencv-python,requests,urllib3,chardet,idna,beautifulsoup4
```

```
# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1
```

```
# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET,CAMERA,RECORD_AUDIO,WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

# (list) features (adds uses-feature -tags to manifest)
#android.features = android.hardware.usb.host

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
android.api = 31
```

```
# (list) The Android archs to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
# In past, was `android.arch` as we weren't supporting builds for multiple archs at the same time.
android.archs = arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a

p4a.hook = camerax_provider/gradle_options.py
```

I tried reverting to my most basic app before reverting my code in kivy python and buildozer, and now it gives that error... is it on my phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, SIGSEGV due to graphics thread. I managed to find a solution. The problem was using kivymd 1.1.1, I specified a different version(1.0.2) in buildozer.spec requirements, and the error was gone.

I attach the reference where I found the solution: https://github.com/Android-for-Python/Android-for-Python-Users#null-pointer-dereference

Comment: thanks for the answer will try it soon, ill keep you updated...

Comment: hey just wanted to let you know that yes the issue is now resolved! thank you very much sir, indeed changing the kivymd version fixed it...